# Differentiating the CDF of a scaled distribution in its scaling factor

Tags: probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations

I am working on a special set of scaled distributions where the CDF $F$ with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ has the following property:

$\forall \mu_1 < \mu $, $F(x,\mu_1 ) > F(x, \mu )$ for $x>0$ and $F(0,\mu_1)\geq F(0,\mu)$.

The normal and Weibull distributions have such properties.

Let $\mu_1 = \mu + \omega$, with $\omega \geq 0$. Name a scaled distribution CDF of $F$ as $G(x,\omega)$.

First question: how can I estimate the sign of  the partial differential in $\omega$ of $\int_0^a G(x,\omega) dx$ for $0<x<a$?

Second question: what is the sign of $\partial G(x,\omega)/\partial \omega$?

Comment: If $\mu_1=\mu$ then of course $F(x,\mu_1)=F(x,\mu)$ for every $x$, so the statement cannot be true for *every* $\mu_1\leq\mu$.

Comment: my mistake, correct the inequality sign $\mu_1<\mu$ in the first sentence.